# Проблема с генерацией apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

Здравствуйте, при генерации apk Grable выдает следующую ошибку.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzln;
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

В консоли Grable выдаёт следующие сообщение

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzln;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzln;\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\n","tool":"Dex"}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка и как её исправить.

Comment: ну вроде вам всё нормально написало. Вы рекламу 2 раза не подключаете случайно? В общем проверяйте ваши зависимости, класс `Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzln` подключён дважды

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Проблема оказалась в этом:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

А нужно было так:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Как прокомментировала IDLE You should use same version com.google.android

Comment: вообще уже версия 25.1.1 библиотек поддержки [как бы доступна](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) ..